# Use a variable in a URL object in Android

Tags: java, android

Can I use a variable in the following code?

```
String Var = "\"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44966/xml%20roma.xml\"";
URL url1 = new URL(Var);
```

Is it only allowed to use a literal string, as in the following line?

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44966/xml%20roma.xml");
```

In my application it is imperative that I use a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the constructor of the URL class accepts a String object, you can pass it directly or through the usage of a variable.

But your string variable, to be equivalent with the example string you present, should be like this:

```
String Var = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44966/xml%20roma.xml";
```